# Sort it "Configure your WhatsApp Sandbox's Inbound URL to change this message"

Tags: api, twilio, chatbot, whatsapp, twilio-programmable-chat

How to sort it so that I can easily help myself and the bot also? And another question how to add the bot into a group? I've tried several times but failed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To update the WhatsApp Sandbox inbound URL you need to visit the [Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp settings page in your Twilio Console](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/settings/whatsapp-sandbox?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Fsms%2Fwhatsapp%2Fsandbox%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1).

[image]

Check out the [documentation for sending and receiving WhatsApp messages with Twilio here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/api).

Sadly, you cannot add your bot to a group message. [WhatsApp deprecated the Groups API in April 2020](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/best-practices-and-faqs#api-specific-questions). You can [implement group chats yourself using the Twilio Conversations API](https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/whatsapp-group-messaging) that make it possible for up to 50 people to communicate through a single WhatsApp business profile.